# response is shown in network but returns empty array when logged in console (React)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm fetching data from api to render it on a component. The network tab on inspect shows the response object.
[image]

My code of the component here:

`

```
const NormalDetails = (props) => {
  const [allCustomers, setAllCustomers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllCustomers = () => {
      try {
        const response = salesService.getAllCustomers();
        if (response.status == 200) {
          setAllCustomers(response.data.object);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error fetching data");
      }
    };
    getAllCustomers();
    console.log(allCustomers);
  }, []);
```

`

But while logging the response in console, it returns an empty array:

[image: console.log result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), **state updates may be asynchronous**, meaning you may not see the updated state instantly.

You are logging `allCustomers` just after you update the state with `setAllCustomers` to `response.data.object`. You might be actually logging the initial state (`[]`) to the console instead of the updated one. try logging the response data itself instead of the state to assure correct response, or add some checking mechanism to `useEffect` to log the state only if its not `[]`.